# In Rails Marshal dumped data is not saving in its full length in mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Marshal dump data is not saving in the database with its full length....why?
I am using the Marshal to dump the objects and its length after dumping is around 
145873
but after saving that data in the mysql its length is changed, means data is missed....
Its length in database is 2851
I have LongText field in the database.
What is the solution to this problem ?

```
      create_table "report_instances", :force => true do |t|
t.integer  "report_id"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.integer  "role_type_id"
t.integer  "delayed_job_id"
t.datetime "generated_at"
t.text     "result"
t.text     "report_data",    :limit => 2147483647
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.boolean  "current",                              :default => true
end


x=Marshal.dump([users, total])

report_instance = report.report_instances.find(:last,:conditions=>["user_id=? and role_type_id=?",usr.id,usr.current_role_type_id])

report_instance.update_attribute(:report_data,x)
```

Comment: show us the insert query, and the table structure.

Comment: x = Marshal.dump([users, total])
report_instance = report.report_instances.find(:last,:conditions=>["user_id=? and role_type_id=?",usr.id,usr.current_role_type_id])
report_instance.update_attribute(:report_data,x)

Comment: Put that into your question. comments aren't a good place for code chunks.

Comment: I have following database

  create_table "report_instances", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "report_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "role_type_id"
    t.integer  "delayed_job_id"
    t.datetime "generated_at"
    t.text     "result"
    t.text     "report_data",    :limit => 2147483647
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.boolean  "current",                              :default => true
  end

Comment: I am new in the stackover flow I just edited my question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i would strongly recommend using a BLOB (with `t.binary`) to store marshaled objects.